# How to customize default linux/unix PAM module faillock to lock user in all nodes in a cluster

Tags: linux, shell-script, pam, lock

I have implemented faillock in all nodes in cluster, so If any user failed login attempts three time through ssh he will be locked for certain period.It is working fine on individual node but I wanted if user lock on one node it should locked on all nodes in that cluster.Currently this is happening on that node only so user are able to login to another nodes.
Example -
ssh admin@10.21.123.34 user tried to login this node and give wrong pwd three times so user is locked on this node.

But he can login to ssh admin@10.21.123.35 easily as he is not locked on this node.

I would like to lock user on other node 10.21.123.34 also if he locked on one node 10.21.123.35. I do not know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to achieve this would be to use a centralized user account database (e.g. LDAP or perhaps Active Directory if one already exists on your site) for the entire cluster. Then the system containing the account database would be responsible for checking the users' passwords for the entire cluster, and any account locks would be immediately effective cluster-wide.

It would also be more convenient for the users, as password changes could be achieved with a single operation and not require logging on to each node individually to change the password.

Although switching to a centralized user account database is a big change in your cluster set-up, it could be worth the effort: as the number of users and systems keeps increasing, there will eventually be a point where maintaining separate user accounts on every host becomes impractical.